# boor-resources doesn't work

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, maas

I have a question, I'm trying do use boot-resources in case of MAAS server here is my command:

```
borek@local:/test$ maas local boot-resources create name="ubuntu1804" title="Custom 18.04" architecture="amd64/generic" content@=Ubuntu-Desktop
```

Basically to be honest my colleague  use exactly the same command on the same server and for him it's working. My output for this command is:

```
usage: maas local [-h] COMMAND ...

Issue commands to the MAAS region controller at $API.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit

drill down:
  COMMAND
    devices           Manage the collection of all the devices in the MAAS.
    files             Manage the collection of all the files in this MAAS.
    machines          Manage the collection of all the machines in the MAAS.
    nodes             Manage the collection of all the nodes in the MAAS.
    rack-controllers  Manage the collection of all rack controllers in MAAS.
    region-controllers
                      Manage the collection of all region controllers in MAAS.
    version           Information about this MAAS instance.

This is a profile.  Any commands you issue on this profile will
operate on the MAAS region server.

The command information you see here comes from the region server's
API; it may differ for different profiles.  If you believe the API may
have changed, use the command's 'refresh' sub-command to fetch the
latest version of this help information from the server.

argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'boot-resources' (choose from 'devices', 'files', 'machines', 'nodes', 'rack-controllers', 'region-controllers', 'version')
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: As it said in the error message,  your `mass` installation doesn't understand "`boot-resources`".

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote, this command works for my teammate without any problems,